# How to export data in a DataGridView to a text file in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I would like know the code, how to export the contents in a `DataGridView1` to a text file in VB.NET.
I am using `Visual Studio 2019`. The table would contain:

Sample:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Item Code | Item Name | Item Description      | Price    | In-Stock | Supplier    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|12345      |Cupboard   |a small sized cupboard |Rs.15,000 |15        |ABC Industry |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|45689      |Chair      |a small chair          |Rs.10,000 |10        |ABC Industry |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
and so on...
```

And in the text file the the data above will be stored as

```
12345|Cupboard|a small sized cupboard|15000|15|ABC Industry
45689|Chair|a small chair|10000|10|ABC Industry
and so on...
```

Thank you
[shannon]

Comment: Please share with us any attempt you have made so far. If there is none, then it's too soon to be asking on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim OPString As String=""

Dim SW As StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(filepath, True)

    Dim grid as DatagridView = DataGridView1
    'print col header names
    For i = 1 To grid.Columns.Count
        OPString  = grid.Columns(i - 1).HeaderText & "|"
    Next
    SW.WriteLine(OPString)
    OPString=""

'Clear the code above if you don't want headers to be added everytime


    'print data
    For i = 0 To grid.RowCount - 2
        For j = 0 To grid.ColumnCount - 1
            OPString = grid(j, i).Value & "|"
        Next
    Next
 SW.WriteLine(OPString)
```

Comment: thanks for the code but i am getting `"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Additional information: Conversion from string "|" to type 'Double' is not valid. occurred"` at the code `OPString  = grid.Columns(i - 1).HeaderText +"|"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
    Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter(filepath, True)

    Dim str As String = String.Empty
    For a As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        str = String.Empty
        For b As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
            str = str & DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(b).Value.ToString & "|"
        Next
        str = str.Substring(0, str.Length - 1)
        sw.WriteLine(str)
    Next
    sw.Close()
```

Comment: i am getting this error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Trifle.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred` at the line `str = str & DataGridView1.Rows(a).Cells(b).Value.ToString & "|"`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a `DataTable` at the source of your `DataGridView`. 
Create as `StringBuilder`.
Reconstitute the `DataTable`.
Loop through the rows in the data table turning each row into an object array.
Change the object array to an array of strings with a little Linq.
Join the string array with a pipe and append the line to the string builder.
When the loop finishes save to a text file.

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    Dim dt = DirectCast(DataGridView1.DataSource, DataTable)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Dim arr = row.ItemArray
        Dim strArr = From element In arr
                     Select CStr(element)
        Dim rowString = String.Join("|", strArr)
        sb.AppendLine(rowString)
    Next
    File.WriteAllText("C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\MyGrid.txt", sb.ToString)
    MessageBox.Show("Finished")
End Sub
```